How to add Quick Action to the Case Detail view in Experience Cloud Site
I want to add my Quick Action button to this list of buttons. The requirement is flexible, so if that's not possible, I'm open to other designs. Whatever is quickest and easiest to implement.

Change Record Type, Edit, Delete all show up in "Case Detail" section here, but I cannot drag my Quick Action Button to "Case Detail", and not to "Custom Buttons" which appears under "Case Detail"


you can create formula fields to return hyperlinks to specific actions and add the formula fields to detail page layouts and visible there https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2020/11/24/autolaunch-navigate-to-quick-actionsurl-hack-in-lightning/
